# event.keyCode and charCode on safari gives "undefined" for german special signs

Tags: javascript, ipad

I am running that function on keyUp:

```
function onKeyUpHandler(e) {
if(!e) var e = window.event;
var code;
if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    else if (e.charCode) code = e.charCode;
if (code < 37 || code > 40) { // not arrows
    //do Stuff;
}
```

it works fine for all chars in most browsers, but Safari (especialy on iPad) gives code as "undefined" (so it doesn't "do stuff") for some special chars like german ä, ü, ß etc. so i cannot check if it's arrow. I am not sure if I should add "or (typeof(code) == 'undefined') ". Could you help me decide what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keyCode` is the only property you need in `keyup` and `keydown` events. It works in all major browsers, including Safari. Here's a better version of your function. I'm not sure if there's another problem or not; let me know if there is.

```
function onKeyUpHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if (code < 37 || code > 40) { // not arrows
        //do Stuff;
    }
}
```

Here is what I consider the definitive page on JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Wow. I don't realy know how, because it looks for me it is just simplified code, but acctualy it helped and it works now! Thx!